# Jquery event listeners aren't carrying over from local to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some Jquery `.hover()` scripts that works fine when developing locally, but when I transfer the files to web server and run the page, the event listeners aren't there.

Here is picture of Chrome's dev console showing event listeners of element when running locally.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QedZXXr.png]

When I upload to server and use Chrome's dev console to check the event listeners for the same element, the `mouseout` and `mouseover` event listeners aren't there.

I have tried uploading to 2 different web server and confirmed that everything was uploaded correctly, all with relative links, etc, and still had same undesired result.

I also searched for a solution for quite a while but to no avail, so hopefully someone here can help me. Friend said people here are nice and open to answering questions.

Not sure if it will help, but here is the script. http://jsfiddle.net/0ytrrtee/

Comment: there are multiple questions... whether the scripts are executed in the web server... can you add some console logging in the script to see whether those are getting executed... whether the elements are added dynamically in the web server(ie after the script is executed)

Comment: Make sure you upload all the files like jquery if your using it to handle events.

Answer (score 0):

On line 76 or your script, you have `$('.alph').load("calls/alpha.html");`
You used Jquery's `.load()`, which dynamically loads content via AJAX. Event listeners won't apply to dynamically loaded unless you delegate.

The reason why it worked locally and not on the web server is because AJAX doesn't usually work locally unless you specifically have it set up. So the script didn't work correctly locally.

Hopefully this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a deep breath. It can be nerve racking to move files from local to a server or from staging to a server. This fear causes us to miss the simplest things. So relax and check each of the suggestions.

Some possible solutions / causes:

1. The JavaScript file is still linked to a local file EX: (src='myfile.js' or src='localhost/myfile.js'). Check your header or footer file to ensure the script is accessible by the server.
2. Check the file and directory permissions to ensure the JavaScript file(s) can be read. Google file permission settings for your server EX: (Windows file permissions)
3. If you are using an older browser, ensure JavaScript is enabled.

If none of these help then create a simple JavaScript file to ensure it can be reached and is able to work on your server. Something like:

```
if(console){
 conole.log('hello world');
}
```